# SQL Query : How to get date reference of Month And Year Column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need a help to change the Month & Year column as Date in Result.

Ex :

**Table Name : AA**

```
Month Year
4     2016
5     2015
```

Result Should Be:

```
01-04-2016
01-05-2015
```

I need a SQL query for this? Can any one help me out?

Comment: Wouldn't it be much easier if you just stored your data in `DATETIME` format?

Comment: Thanks lot . I got it.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this,

```
DECLARE @AA TABLE (
    Month INT
    ,Year INT
    )

INSERT INTO @AA (
    Month
    ,Year
    )
VALUES (
    4
    ,2016
    )
    ,(
    5
    ,2015
    )

SELECT convert(DATE, convert(VARCHAR(50), year * 10000 + month * 100 + 01)) AS DATE
FROM @AA
```

Comment: Thanks lot . I got it.

Comment: if it helps you can mar it as answer @Kapil

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
select '01-'+cast([month] as nvarchar) + '-'+cast([Year] as nvarchar)
from YourTable
```

Comment: Thanks lot . I got it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming int data types:

```
DECLARE @Month int = 4, @Year int = 2016

SELECT CAST(CAST(@Year * 10000 + @Month * 100 + 01 As char(8)) as date)
```

Assuming char/varchar data types:

```
DECLARE @MonthString varchar(2) = 4, @YearString char(4) = 2016

SELECT CAST(@YearString +'-'+ RIGHT('00' + @MonthString, 2) + '-01' as date)
```

Results in both cases:

```
2016-04-01 -- (Date data type)
```

Comment: Thanks lot . I got it.

Answer (score 0):

Add square brackets for the reserve keywords:

```
DECLARE @AA TABLE ([Month] INT, [Year] INT);

INSERT INTO @AA ([Month], [Year]) VALUES 
(4, 2016),
(5, 2015);

SELECT '01-' + RIGHT('00' + CAST([MONTH] AS VARCHAR), 2) + '-' + CAST([Year] AS VARCHAR)  
FROM @AA
```

Result:

```
01-04-2016
01-05-2015
```

Comment: Thanks lot . I got it.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @Table1 TABLE 
    (Month int, Year int)
;

INSERT INTO @Table1
    (Month, Year)
VALUES
    (4, 2016),
    (5, 2015)
;

select '01'+'-'+RIGHT('000'+CAST(Month AS VARCHAR(3)),2)+'-'+CAST(Year AS VARCHAR) from @Table1
```

Comment: but OP wants the result as `Date` instead of `Varchar` ?

Comment: Thanks lot . I got it.

Answer (score 0):

Do not do varchar convertions. Use like below

```
declare @t table([Month] int,[Year] int)
insert into @t 
select 4,     2016 union all
select 5,     2015

select dateadd(month,month-1,dateadd(year,[year]-1900,0)) from @t
```

Comment: Thanks lot . I got it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use concat function to acieve this

```
SELECT CONCAT('01-',year,'-',month) as req_date from tableName
```

Comment: Thanks lot . I got it.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
declare @y varchar(4)='2015'
declare @m varchar(2)='5'
--try_prase is available starting sql 2012
print try_parse('01-'+@m+'-'+@y as datetime using 'en-us')
print convert(datetime,'01-'+@m+'-'+@y,121)
```

Comment: Question is about 2008 version... try parse does not apply here.

Comment: Thanks lot . I got it.

Comment: cool, then use one options specified here
but be careful string manipulations are expensive on sql server - use them wisely. Use query execution estimation plan to decide on your best option.